# Upload images ends up as .txt in Laravel using Paperclip

Tags: laravel, image, file, upload, paperclip

I'm trying to upload a picture to my model in Laravel, so I decided to use Czim/Paperclip library. Here's my configuration files:

In my migration file, I've added the following:

```
$table->string('image_file_name')->nullable();
$table->integer('image_file_size')->nullable();
$table->string('image_content_type')->nullable();
$table->timestamp('image_updated_at')->nullable();
$table->string('image_variants', 255)->nullable();
```

In my app/config/filesystems.php, I've added the paperclip disk:

```
'paperclip' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => public_path('storage'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

My model with paperclip reference:

```
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->hasAttachedFile('image', [
            'variants' => [
                'medium' => [
                    'auto-orient' => [],
                    'resize'      => ['dimensions' => '300x300'],
                ],
                'thumb' => '100x100',
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'variants' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
```

The thing is this: If I upload a png or jpg image, the file is stored in this path `public\storage\App\User\000\000\007`, but not in that format. I have 3 folders in there (original, medium, thumb), which contains the `a7b7a025f3630860.txt` file. In the txt, its the name of the uploaded picture.

I ended up adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into my form, but with this enctype added, my images are null (they're not uploading). If I remove the enctype from the form, they upload in that path, but as .txts.

Here's a `dd($request->image)` from my store method:

```
"image" => UploadedFile {#295 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "5.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
    filename: "php6E88.tmp"
    basename: "php6E88.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php6E88.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php6E88.tmp"
    aTime: 2019-06-27 10:40:36
    mTime: 2019-06-27 10:40:36
    cTime: 2019-06-27 10:40:36
    inode: 0
    size: 9486
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php6E88.tmp"
  }
```

Controller method looks like this:

```
$receipe = new Receipt();

 $receipe->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
 $receipe->name = $request->get('name');
 $receipe->body = $request->get('body');
 $receipe->url = $request->get('url');
 $receipe->cooking_time = $request->get('cooking_time');
 $receipe->image = $request->get('image');

 $receipe->save();
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you,

Comment: Please check all the steps in `https://github.com/czim/laravel-paperclip`. Also, you have not shown the code for the controller.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, all steps from that link. My controller looks like this:

Comment: Try by replacing ` $receipe->image = $request->get('image');` with ` $receipe->image = $request->file('image');`

Comment: It work ffs!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changed the store method in controller from 
`$receipe->image = $request->get('image');` to `$receipe->image = $request->file('image');`